# Elementオブジェクトから子要素を取り出すには

Tags: javascript, html

javascriptで下記のDOM要素?を取得したのですが、子要素の`.dlcard > dlcard__thumbnail > img`のようにアクセスしたいです。どのような関数を使用したらよいでしょうか？ 要素はinputという変数に格納されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**追記**
説明不足ですいません。
inputに格納されたelementオブジェクトから要素を取り出す方法はないでしょうか？
querySelectorだと全体のhtmlからとういう事になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.querySelector()を使えばいいでしょう。

[Document.querySelector() - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
var el = document.querySelector(".dlcard > .dlcard__thumbnail > img");
```

---

追記

> inputに格納されたelementオブジェクトから要素を取り出す

[Element.querySelector() - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var img = input.querySelector(".dlcard > .dlcard__thumbnail > img");
console.log(img);
```

Comment: 普通にquerySelector使用出来るんですね。知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`input.childNodes`を使用する事で子要素にアクセス出来ました。